# Parsing the log file using select-String

Tags: powershell

Team,
Thanks in advance, I'm an ITPro and learning PowerShell. I've a log file which has the data in below format. I've attached the image.
I'm finding all the line which has finished transfer in it and then running foreach loop to find the line in which the date matches the current date using -eq operator

I wanted to then get the specific file name from that current line where the foreach loop is running. Example from my sample : first finished transfer line in the log matches the current date hence i wanted to get the file name which is HardwareEvents.evtx.

But I'm unable to find any method which can help me parse a file name in the current running for each line.

If i get the file name i can then delete the file using powersell cmdlet.

```
        $var = Select-String -Path "C:\Creds\AzCopyVerbose.log" -Pattern 'Finished Transfer' | `
Select-Object -Last 20 | ForEach-Object `
    {
      if (($_.Line).Substring(1,10) -eq (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd'))
      {
        $_.Line. // There is no method which I'm aware of need help in this if statement
      }
      Else {Write-Host "The date present in the azcopy verbose log is older"}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the data to search through as text not as a picture. I think a single RegEx possibly with look arounds can filter the relevant file names with capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the filenames from the log where the date is for today, you can use this:

```
$logfile = 'C:\Creds\AzCopyVerbose.log'
$today = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y/%m/%d"
$pattern = '^\[(?<date>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}).*Finished transfer:\s+(?<filename>.*)\s+=>.*$'
Select-String -Path $logfile -Pattern $pattern | Select-Object -Last 20 | ForEach-Object {
    $null = $_.Line -match $pattern
    if ($matches['date'] -eq $today) {
        Write-Host $matches['filename']
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "The date present in the azcopy verbose log is older"
    }
}
```

Instead of using `Select-String`, you can also do this which requires to match the pattern only once, so a bit cleaner in my opinion:

```
$logfile = 'C:\Creds\AzCopyVerbose.log'
$today = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y/%m/%d"
$pattern = '^\[(?<date>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}).*Finished transfer:\s+(?<filename>.*)\s+=>.*$'
Get-Content -Path $logfile | Select-Object -Last 20 | Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($matches['date'] -eq $today) {
        Write-Host $matches['filename']
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "The date present in the azcopy verbose log is older"
    }
}
```

p.s. I use `Get-Date -UFormat "%Y/%m/%d"` because `(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')` on my Dutch machine outputs `2018-11-10`

**Regex Details**

```
^                     Assert position at the beginning of the string
\[                    Match the character “[” literally
(?<date>              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “date”
   \d                 Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}             Exactly 4 times
   \/                 Match the character “/” literally
   \d                 Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}             Exactly 2 times
   \/                 Match the character “/” literally
   \d                 Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}             Exactly 2 times
)
.                     Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Finished\ transfer:   Match the characters “Finished transfer:” literally
\s                    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +                  Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<filename>          Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “filename”
   .                  Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\s                    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +                  Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
=>                    Match the characters “=>” literally
.                     Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$                     Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks Theo for teaching me a newer way to achieve this and i learnt a new thing today. Thanks once again.
Only one thing i wanted to know, how did you created the regex pattern?  can you please guide me through a link or the way you created this? It would be helpful. Thanks once again.

Comment: @aquib.rocks I have added the details for the regex. I always use RegexBuddy (not free..), but you can also experiment on https://regex101.com/

Comment: you are more than awesome my friend, i was confused as to how the regex knew the file name, when you haven't written any code. but now i know through your explanation that it automatically know that anything before the => is the file name through regex.

(?<filename>.*)\s+=>.*$'


Thanks brother for all the help.

Comment: Nice, but even with `Select-String` you don't have to match twice, because you can access the capture groups via `$_.Matches[0].Groups`, e.g., `$_.Matches[0].Groups['filename'].Value`. You don't have to resort to a Unix date format to ensure _literal_ use of `/`; simply `\ `-escape it (or use embedded quoting): `Get-Date -Format "yyyy\/MM\/dd"`

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53239181/45375):

It is not obvious, but **it *is* possible to access a `Select-String` command's [named] capture-group matches in a `ForEach-Object` script block** (no need to repeat matching with `-match`):

```
PS> '... File transfer: C:\path\to\file => ...' |
      Select-String '\bFile transfer: (?<file>.+?) =>' | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['file'].Value }
C:\path\to\file  # Value of named capture group 'file'
```

- `$_.Matches` is the collection of matches for the current input line; unless `-AllMatches` was specified, there's only *one* entry, with index `0`.
- `.Groups` accesses the collection of capture-group matches (with the entry at index `0` containing the overall match).
- `['file']` accesses the match for named capture group `file`, but note that at *index*-based access works equally (for unnamed capture groups), starting with index `1`; that is, `$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value` in the command above would have yielded the same result.

In terms of data types, `Select-String` emits [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances, whose `.Matches` property is an array of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instances.

Comment: My pleasure, @aquib.rocks. I've added a paragraph with links to the data types involved to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an approach using regex for date.

```
$var = Select-String -Path "C:\Creds\AzCopyVerbose.log" -Pattern 'Finished Transfer' | 
Select-Object -Last 20 | ForEach-Object -Process {
      $_.Line -match '\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}' | Out-Null
      [string]$Match = $Matches.Values
      if ([Datetime]$Match -eq (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd'))
      {
        $_.Line. // There is no method which I'm aware of need help in this if statement
      }
      Else {Write-Host "The date present in the azcopy verbose log is older"}
    }
```